# iPad launch orientation when flat on surface

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I have the following code:

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] UIInterface];

    if(orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"Device Landscape");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Device Portrait");
    }

 }
```

This works perfectly for the simulator and on the device but only if the iPad is not flat on a surface, for example if i lay the iPad on my desk and load the view it will say its portrait and so I cant detect the orientation when the view appears.

Any ideas of the best way to detect the interface orientation when the viewWillAppear is called?

Thanks

Comment: Well, what do you want your app to do if the iPad is in fact FaceUp?

Comment: He wants to know wether or not to show the view in landscape or portrait when device is laying flat.

Comment: I have a subview thats is displayed in a difference place depending if the view is landscape/portrait. So i need to know which orientation the interface is when the viewAppears.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use `[self interfaceOrientation]` instead of the device orientation.

Comment: What about in iOS 12 (or 8+)?

Answer (score 9):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` also works if you are somewhere in the code that does not have access to `[self interfaceOrientation]`

Answer (score 0):

First, do you know about the interfaceOrientation property of UIViewController? It looks like you are trying to duplicate it. If you really want to do that, simply subscribe to device orientation change notifications, check if the new orientation is valid interface orientation (the is a macro for that) and if yes, store the value to some variable (like lastSeenOrientation). Then you can rely on that value wherever you want.